# How to refer to all cells in any one section of a tableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Say I have a tableView with 3 sections, and I want it so that if I press any one cell in the first section, all cells in that section change to a set colour. How do I refer to all cells within a single section?

I currently have this working, but only to the extent of whichever cell you press changes colour, and I need it to change all the cells.

Currently I am setting the constant `cell` to `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)`, and then directly referring to `cell?.backgroundColor`. I do this within my `didSelectRowAt indexPath:` function, so I press a cell, and it changes colour, but I need to change all cells within the same section as the one pressed.

Any help would be great, as I can't find any information on doing this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do this like anything else you should do in a table view. Update the data model as needed and then reload either the whole table (`reloadData` or just the relevant index paths (either `reloadRows` or `reloadSections`).

In your case you need to update your data model such that your `cellForRowAt` or `willDisplay:forRowAt:` methods update the cell with the appropriate background color.

Since you want to reload an entire section, after updating the data model, use the `reloadSections` method of the table view to reload just that one section.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method in your `didSelectRowAt indexPath:`

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
                animated:(BOOL)animated 
          scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition;
```

Call this function in loop such that it covers all row in 1st section and inside your `didSelectRowAt indexPath:` write a logic that will highlight  a particular row.

Another method would be use `[tableview reloaData]` and manipulate your modal such a way that when user clicks any row in 1st section it sets a flag for all row in your array for 1st section. and in `cellForRowAtIndexpath:` implement logic that if flag is set then highlight that row

Answer (score 0):

1. Create dictionary with section colors.

   ```
   var dict: [Int: UIColor] = [1: UIColor.red, 2: UIColor.blue]
   ```
2. Setup color in cellForIndexPath:

   ```
   cell.backgroundColor = dict[indexPath.section]
   ```
3. Detect touch in didSelectRow and change color in dict and reload section:

   ```
   dict[indexPath.section] = UIColor.blue
   reloadSections(...
   ```

I think there is no possibility to get list of cell for section because of `UITableView` cache system. Only possibility is iterate `indexPath` and calling `tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)`